# Electron Atom - Module "Node-Windows" not found after compiling

Tags: module, compiler-errors, electron, node-windows

After hours of searching and still not finding a usefull answer, I hope somebody could help me with following issue that I'm facing:

I inclued to my Electron APP a module called "node-windows" so I could register a script as a service to a windows machine.

I've installed it over the command 
 => npm install -g node-windows

and linked it to my project path with:
 => npm link node-windows

However if I try to compile my Project with EPI with or without asar source packaging, and start up the compiled EXE, I'm getting following error from the DeveloperTools:

Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'node-windows'

As long the project isn't compiled yet, everything works fine.
I already checked that the module is linked to the folder node_modules in the APP Directory as also in the npm folder in the AppData directory.

What could I've been missing or what could I check to get this working?

Thank you already very much for an answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok here my Solution. Guess this was an absolutely noobie mistake ^^

I've forgot to include the module to the package.json file.
I did this with "npm install -g node-windows --save-dev" & "npm install -g node-windows --save".
After that it worked.